# How to refresh Node and Cheerio code on HTML webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

I used an online tutorial to build a simple web scraper to scrape links using Node JS and Cheerio. The output (links) is pasted on my HTML webpage I made. However, every time I want to update the page, I have to run the Node JS code using the terminal. I would like to automate it so that it automatically runs/refreshes like every 1 minute.

Is there a code that will allow me to automatically refresh/run the script every 1 minute after starting it? I've searched throughout Google, YouTube, and Stackoverflow, but wasn't able to find what I was looking for. There are some explanations that say you can use Puppeteer to scrape dynamic websites like Twitter, but I'm just trying to keep it simple and make something that'll update every 10 minutes, whether there is new content or not. I appreciate any help!

Comment: How about a cron job?

Comment: @horia Hmm, I'm not really familiar with cron, but from what I just read, I have to install it to my files and then keep my terminal/javascript running? I was looking more for something that would run in the background simply when I click a button on my HTML file (and I can auto-refresh the HTML so its updated).